# React Material UI extremely slows VSCode autocompletion with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, material-ui

Importing the `"@mui/material"` will stuck the VSCode - so TS warnings will come up after 10-15s instead of less than 10ms, for example:

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
// and make a use with this button.
```

Then:

```
new Date(). // will show the autocomplion very slow
```

If you remove the import of that button, or any module from this package, everything works great again.

Comment: Do you have `files.watcherExclude` configured?

Comment: where? I have excluded node modules in tsconfig.

Comment: In the vscode settings.

Comment: It seems that it is default excluded from vscode, so it might not be the case if you've not override it by yourself, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34801

Comment: No I didn't change anything

Answer (score -2):

To import components, use path imports instead of top-level imports:

```js
// ❌ top-level imports
// import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material'

// ✅ path imports
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
```

This will speed up Typescript autocompletion.